# Python Nested conditional? double condition followed by another condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

Im trying to learn python but struggling on this problem.

Imagine this situations:

1- user press button1 and button2 =
program need to "do some"

2 - user press button1 and button2 then press button3 =
Its ok to me "do some 2"

3 - user press button2 and button1 then press button3 =
Its ok to me "do some 2"

but

4 - if user press button3 before button1 and button2 =
Its not ok to me "do some2", I need just to "do some"

**so the sequence of which button is pressed first matters to my purpose**

```
def button1_pressed():  # Returns true if the left mouse button is pressed
    button1_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    return button1_state < 0

def button2_pressed():  # Returns true if the right mouse button is pressed
    button2_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)
    return  button2_state < 0

def button3_pressed():  # Returns true if the M button is pressed
    button3_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x4D)
    return button3_state < 0

while True:
    while button1_pressed() and button2_pressed(): # No matter which one is pressed first to me
        print("do some")
        while button3_pressed(): # Only if it is pressed after button1 and button2 are pressed
            print("do some2")
            if button2_pressed() == 0:
                break # this only breaks the inner while loop
        break # added an extra break else it would just be stuck in an endless loop
```

I will be thankfull if anyone give me some help.

Comment: Why do we have this in a loop? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is what's called a "state machine".  The situations you describe are called "states", and they persist after the button presses have stopped (e.g. you can be in the state "the user has pressed button 2", which is different from "the user is pressing button 2").

```
pressed = [True, False, False, False]
while True:
  if button1_pressed() and not pressed[1]:
      pressed[1] = True
      if pressed[2]:
          print("do some")
          continue
  if button2_pressed() and not pressed[2]:
      pressed[2] = True
      if pressed[1]:
          print("do some")
          continue
  if button3_pressed() and not pressed[3]:
      pressed[3] = True
      if pressed[1] and pressed[2]:
          print("do some 2")
  if all(pressed):
      # All the buttons have been pressed (in some order).  Done!
      break
```

You could potentially encode this in a data structure, something like this:

```
buttons = [lambda: False, button1_pressed, button2_pressed, button3_pressed]
pressed = [False, False, False, False]
actions = {
    # For each button press, what action happens 
    # based on button(s) previously pressed.
    1: ([2], "do some")
    2: ([1], "do some")
    3: ([1, 2], "do some 2")
}
while True:
    for num in (1, 2, 3):
        if not buttons[num]() or pressed[num]:
            continue
        pressed[num] = True
        prev, action = actions[num]
        if all(pressed[p] for p in prev):
            print(action)
    if any(
        not pressed_now() and was_pressed
        for pressed_now, was_pressed in zip(buttons, pressed)
    ):
        # Break condition: previously pressed button was released
        break
```

Comment: +1 for the state machine; I'm more fond of using a list of named states (START, AFTER_DUAL_PUSH, AFTER_PUSH_2, etc.), but the idea is the same.

Comment: I apreciate your help, but I need it while the buttons are pressed. I think i did not make my self clear enought, my bad. So the consequences need to be executed only if the user is pressing the buttons. So if user stop pressing button 1 or 2 all loop is gone. If use stops pressing M, the inner loop stops only. Sorry spelling mistakes, english isnt my first language.

Comment: Oh gotcha, so as soon as they let go of a button, it needs to break?  That's actually pretty easy, lemme modify my answer a bit.

Comment: Sort of.. If user is pressing in this order: button 1 + button 2 = do some (the order of this button do not matter), but if press button 1 + button 2  + M (in this order) = do some2, but if M + button 1 or 2 + button 1 or 2 = do some (M before button 1 or 2 matter, but the order of 1 or 2 after M dont matter). In the last case, if the M is realead, the do some2 need to become/turn into do some.

Comment: I'm having trouble following that, but I think if you read over this code and can understand how it works, it should be close enough to whatever you're trying to do that you can figure out how to adapt it.  :)

Comment: In other words, the "do some 2" is a "do some amplificated" and the button M is the "catalyzer".. so anytime M is released the "do some2" (stronger) become "do some" (weaker)

Comment: yeah, im having troubles to make it clear, anyway thank your for trying to help me...